# Why was my edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, moderators, editing, specific-question

I [edited this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7463), and Keshav rejected the edit.

1. I edited the tags. This was the main purpose for my edit, as I said in the summary. Is it really better for it to be untagged than to have the descriptive tags I added?
2. I edited the title for grammar. Is it really better to have bad grammar in a question's title?
3. I made minor edits to the body, with the thinking that they aided readability. If you disagree, fine, but is that really a valid basis to reject the whole edit?

I'm miffed, not because I see this particular edit/question as that big of a deal, but because I'm always a bit annoyed when contributions I make to a site are rejected; it makes me feel like I may as well not contribute. And in this case, I don't even see how there could be a *grey* area here. It seems like an unquestionably positive contribution was rejected... by a mod, no less.

Was there a legitimate reason to reject my edit? Should I have edited differently?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your edit summary that said it was edited for tags.  I just saw your edits to the title and body, and I thought they were pretty minor and didn't improve the post that much, especially things like adding "I feel", so I didn't see notice that you also edited the tags.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Should I resubmit the edit? If so, should I only include the tag edits this time?

Comment: Yeah sure, go ahead.

Comment: I think if this is solved than please answer the question so that the thread gets closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status report: Everything is fine. Nothing is ruined.